# Type 1 fonts render poorly on-screen

Tags: fonts

Some Type 1 fonts, particularly URW Palladio L, look rather ugly when rendered on-screen in various programs.  In particular, the letter height is inconsistent.

The header text is Nimbus Sans L, also a Type 1 font; sometimes, it looks acceptable, but sometimes its baseline isn't clean.

I have this problem in most programs.  OpenOffice and AbiWord both display it with URW Palladio.  I similarly have problems with Nimbus Sans embedded in PDFs displayed in Evince.

Any suggestions as to how to fix this?  Settings I can tweak somewhere to make it work properly?

Comment: I think they're just poorly-kerned fonts.  Though, Firefox and Open Office have their own built-in font rendering engines instead of using the system-wide ones (because they are cross-platform apps).  And Evince uses Poppler...  I'd file bugs with upstream font designers about the bad kerning.

Comment: I assume you've experimented with the rendering settings on the font tab of System>Preferences>Appearance?

Comment: @misterben Yep, some at least.  There is probably another permutation or two I can try.

Comment: @misterben I tried a few more permutations, and found that the default "Subpixel" setting actually does fix it in AbiWord, etc.  That just left the issue of Firefox; turns out that Firefox actually uses `~/.fonts.conf`, which was set to medium rather than slight hinting. URW Palladio doesn't hint well at medium.  Nimbus Sans still has a messed-up baseline, though.  If you want to write up an answer, I can accept it unless someone comes w/ a great answer that fixes Nimbus Sans too.

Comment: I've added an answer. It may be worth you adding detail of your ~/.fonts.conf changes for the benefit of anyone reading this question later, as it's not as easy to work out as the GUI rendering settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tinkering with the rendering settings on the font tab of System>Preferences>Appearance should let you fine-tune the appearance. The hinting (instructions on how to best suggest the shape of the letters at low resolution) on some fonts doesn't work well with the default settings.

[This Ubuntu Wiki entry](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Fonts) has some explanation of font settigns in Ubuntu.

Comment: To complete the change, I had to edit ~/.fonts.conf to set the `hintstyle` assignment to `hintslight`.  URW Palladio does not hint well with medium hinting (which is unfortunate, since I prefer the medium-hinted aesthetic for everything else).

Comment: That's weird - I thought accepting the answer was enough to issue the bounty. I guess I was supposed to issue it separately for full credit to happen.